# Switch between four languages using cookies and mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, switch-statement

I have four columns in a database that contains four languages, German, French, Dutch and English.
How can I switch between these languages when I set the language to one of them using cookies?
when i set lang. in cookie
example:

```
                            $lang=$_COOKIE["setlanguge"];
                            if($lang=="EN"){echo"fighters";}
                            elseif($lang=="FR"){echo"Chefs";}
                            elseif($lang=="DE"){echo"Lebensführer";}
                            elseif($lang=="LN"){echo"Levensleiders";}
                            else{echo"fighters";}
```

i have in my trans. table
col. en contain: fighters
col. fr contain: Chefs
col. de contain: Lebensführer
col. ln contain: Levensleiders
my question is when i set en lang. for example, How can I change the words according to the table in the database using cookies?

Comment: Can you provide example of the table structure and the code which selects strings from there?

Comment: $sql="CREATE TABLE `trans` (
`id` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `en` VARCHAR( 222 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `fr` VARCHAR( 222 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `de` VARCHAR( 222 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
 `ln` VARCHAR( 444 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',

PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COMMENT =  'Images Information Table';";

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get method instead of cookie.

Fetch the languages list in select

```
<form>
  <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="language" >
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="EN">EN</option>
        <option value="FR">FR</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Then Get The value from php

```
if(isset($_GET["language"])){
       $lang= $_GET["language"];

            if($lang=="EN"){echo"fighters";}
            elseif($lang=="FR"){echo"Chefs";}
            elseif($lang=="DE"){echo"Lebensführer";}
            elseif($lang=="LN"){echo"Levensleiders";}
             else{echo"fighters";} 
        }
```

Comment: by cookies. a select lang. will become website lang.